# How do I restore a deleted Adobe AfterEffects built in workspace?

Tags: workspace, adobe-after-effects

I was trying to tweak the After Effects UI  panels by creating and saving custom Workspaces. However the list became bloated and I decided to quickly delete off some workspaces.

However I just realized I deleted some native workspaces like the **All Panels** and **Animation** workspaces. I have tried to access the Workspace list via the Menu `>>Window>>Workspace` and via the Dropdown menu at the right of the `Tools panel` but they are not listed in either places.

How do I restore/recover these deleted workspaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally fixed it with a simple edit to the `Workspaces.xml` file. Usually most applications (*on Windows platform*) store user modifiable settings/preferences in the `Roaming` folder that are loaded at the splash-screen stage when the application is started. Adobe products also follow suite.

Am using Adobe `After Effects CC` and its user variables are located in.

> C:\Users\**myUserName**\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\After Effects\**12.2**

It's in this folder that you will find the  `Workspaces.xml` file. On examining it in a text editor, the Workspaces you deleted will not be listed among the `<ustring>` array entries.(In my case the *All Panels* and *Animation* entries were not listed.)

Add the missing Workspace names as separate ustring entries. In my case, all I did was to add them to the file again as shown in screenshot below(my additions to the file are highlighted in yellow).

---

[image: Screenshot of the Workspaces.xml file after adding the deleted entires]

> I have a feeling though that this is just a rough fix, that there is a
>   better way of solving this. Any one with a much cleaner approach?

Answer (score 1):

I did some similar experiment with the workspace and found your post when I was trying to recover the default workspace.

I found a possibly easier solution, in which at least you don't have to type. Just the delete the `workspaces.xml` and AE will regenerate the file when opened next time. And all the default workspaces will be restored.